# Undefined ao passar parâmetro para uma função JS e Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, paginação

Tenho uma função que recebe como parâmetro um `value` vindo do HTML, porém, ele está vindo `undefined`. Estou usando JS e Angular.

Meu HTML

```
<div class="input-group  col-lg-3  col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-left">
   <select onchange="carregarDistritos()" id="idSelecionaSize" class="form-control" data-pager-action='pagesize'>
      <option value="5">Ver 5</option>
      <option value="15">Ver 15</option>
      <option value="20">Ver 20</option>
      <option value="25">Ver 25</option>
      <option value="50">Ver 50</option>
      <option value="100">Ver 100</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Meu JS

```
app.controller("buscaDistritoController", function($scope,  $http, $location) {



    $scope.distritos = [];
    $scope.distrito = {}; // binding com o form

    $(document).ready(function() {
          var e = document.getElementById("idSelecionaSize");
            var size = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    });



    carregarDistritos = function() {

        token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");

        var search = $location.search();
        var page = search.page||0;
        var size = search.size||size;
        var sort = search.sort||'type,desc';


        $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: '/user/distritosPaginacao?page=' + page + '&size=' + size + '&sort=' + sort
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.distritos = response.data.content;
            $scope.page = response.data.totalPages;
            $scope.sort = sort;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });

    };
});
```

Comment: Qual seria esse parâmetro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está utilizando o angular, mas esta recuperando o valor utilizando o JQuery. Quando o $(document).ready é disparado, o valor do "size" realmente está undefined.

Minha sugestão é utilizar a propriedade ng-model do angular, que é a forma adequada de se recuperar valores dos inputs vindos do HTML, e chamar seu método no ng-change.

Exemplo HTML:

```
<div class="input-group  col-lg-3  col-md-3  col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-left">
<select ng-change="carregarDistritos()" ng-model="size" class="form-control" data-pager-action='pagesize'>
      <option value="5">Ver 5</option>
      <option value="15">Ver 15</option>
      <option value="20">Ver 20</option>
      <option value="25">Ver 25</option>
      <option value="50">Ver 50</option>
      <option value="100">Ver 100</option>    </select> </div>
```

EXEMPLO Controller:

```
carregarDistritos = function() {

        token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");

        var search = $location.search();
        var page = search.page||0;
        var size = search.size||$scope.size;
        var sort = search.sort||'type,desc';


        //restante do seu código//

    };
```

Você pode conferir um exemplo [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-change.asp)